# How to set active in cssmenu

Tags: html, css

Hi all this is the css code used for the script.. I wanted to set the active status for the same once clicked on tabs..

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #47c9af;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 18px 25px 12px 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444444;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -moz-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:active > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover:after {
  background: #47c9af;
}
#cssmenu ul > li:active{
    background-color: #47c9af;
}
```

and the html is mentioned as below..

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Products</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Company</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

But when i selected the tabs the active is not getting changed...

Answer (score 0):

I think li element cannot be active, anchor element (a) can be active so you should just use

```
a:active
```

without

```
li:active
```

in front of it.

Or if you need to set the LI element active, you can use javascript for adding a class to clicked li element and then style .active class

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried to change as a:active, Its not getting accepted..  Do you recommend to remove this #cssmenu ul > li:active{
    background-color: #47c9af;
} and add javascript

Comment: But please keep in mind that if you licked the link and new page is loaded than it will not be active any more. It will work only when navigation on one page to different sections. In your case you will most likely need to pre-add some additional class to the links on different pages. If you have for example, home.html and about.html pages then on home.html page add "active" class to the menu element corresponsing to home and on about.html add same class to corresponding menu item and then style li.active as you need.